# solaris tail on ubuntu

Tags: scripts, tail, solaris

Is there a way to make linux `tail` understand the Solaris `tail` syntax (precisely like `tail +2`)? The short story is that I have some update scripts written for Solaris on the repo and I *cannot* modify them in a proper way and commit. Now I'm dealing with it by manual patching the scripts locally (adding `-c` for `tail +2`), running, and rolling back after. Another idea I have is to make a "wrapper" around `/usr/bin/tail` which would parse the argument list and add the `-c` option for `tail` if necessary. Not sure if it is correct though.